# javascript addClass doesn't seem to trigger my css for the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap nav-pills and have changed the background color. When the page first loads it puts the correct background color. But after my javascript file changes which li is 'active' it doesn't seem to respond to the css.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li id="About" role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li id="Animals" role="presentation"><a href="#">Animals</a></li>
  <li id="Adoptly" role="presentation"><a href="#">Adoptly</a></li>
  <li id="Blog" role="presentation"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li id="Events" role="presentation"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
    color:white !important;
    background-color:#FF4571 !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
 function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    var displayText = current[0].textContent;

    if (windowsize > 425) {
        //if the window is greater than 440px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
        $( "#navigation" ).empty();
        $( "#navigation" ).html(pillsHTML);
        checkActive(displayText,true);
    }
    else
        {
           $( "#navigation" ).empty();
           $( "#navigation" ).html(listHTML);
           checkActive(displayText,false);
        }
}

function checkActive(currentTab, bool){
    console.log(bool);
    if(bool)
        {
           $('li').removeClass('active');
           var element = document.getElementById(currentTab);
           $(element).addClass('active');
        }
    else
        {
            $('.list-group-item').removeClass('active');
            var element = document.getElementById(currentTab);
            $(element).addClass('active');
        }
}

checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$( window ).resize(checkWidth);

$('#navigation').on('click','li',function(e){
  var previous = $(this).closest(".nav").children(".active");
  previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
  $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated list-item
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here: Your `ul` tag in the HTML doesn't have an `id="navigation"`, and the result of your `e.target` are the `<a />` tags, not their parent `<li />` which your styles are set up for.

So add the `id="navigation"` and switch your addClass line to:

```
$(e.target).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

And you should be good to go.

**Edit:** Here's a Codepen as well just to illustrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaOmbz

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the codepen. Makes it so much easier to see the concept you were talking about.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help